# Using condition instead of assignment in first part of for header in C

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

Why is this allowed in C??? And what does it do? Full program can be seen here even though it is not necessary http://www.learntosolveit.com/cprogramming/Ex_1.18_remtrailbt.html

```
for (i > 0; ((s[i] == ' ') || (s[i] == '\t')); --i)
```

Comment: This is a significant historic code construction known as a “mistake.” The author intended to prevent decreasing `i` below zero (or below −1, but their design is flawed, so the complete intent is unclear) but wrote incorrect code.

Comment: @Jabberwocky What does this code even do? I have never seen this before. It is not allowed in Java.

Comment: @madcobra Java is not C. See the answer below.

Comment: K&R (either edition) is a much richer source of learning C examples than just about anywhere.   They insist on a clean, concise and readable style; and have many examples showing how idiomatic shorthand improves the readability of programs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first clause of a `for` statement is either a declaration or (as in this case) an expression in a void context.  What this means is that the first clause is evaluated for its side effects, typically an assignment which is a type of expression.

Section 6.8.5.3 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) defines the `for` statement as follows:

> *1* The statement
>
> > for (*clause-1*; *expression-2*; *expression-3*) *statement*
>
> behaves  as  follows:  The  expression expression-2 is  the 
>   controlling  expression  that  is evaluated  before  each  execution 
>   of  the  loop  body.   The  expression expression-3 is evaluated  as 
>   a  void  expression  after  each  execution  of  the  loop  body.   If
>   clause-1 is  a declaration, the scope of any identifiers it declares
>   is the remainder of the declaration and the entire loop, including the
>   other two expressions; it is reached in the order of execution before
>   the first evaluation of the controlling expression.  **If clause-1 is an
>   expression, it is evaluated as a void expression before the first
>   evaluation of the controlling expression.**
>
> *2* Both clause-1 and expression-3 can be omitted.  An omitted expression-2 is replaced by a nonzero constant.

So any expression is allowed in the first clause of a `for` statement.  In this particular case the expression `i > 0` is evaluated but has no side effect, so it effectively does nothing.  It is the same as:

```
for (; ((s[i] == ' ') || (s[i] == '\t')); --i)
```

Comment: Not a fan of side effects. Dense programming + the side effect wont execute for certain.

Comment: @madcobra Technically, any assignment in C is a side effect since an assignment expression takes on the value that was assigned (with the actual assignment being the side effect), so you can do things like `if ((result=foo()) == 0)`

Comment: That is another thing I hate about C. I encountered this feature earlier in my book and i wrote "Yikes. Nice Code." next to it. I should just close this C book and go back to Java lol.

Answer (score 4):

> Why is this allowed in C?

Why should it not be allowed? The initialiser part of a `for` loop can contain an expression, or a declaration, or just be empty. `i > 0` is an expression like any other. Trying to somehow limit what goes there to just expressions with side effects would complicate the language for little benefit.

Compilers are free to emit warnings about such strange code as a Quality of Implementation issue, if they wish.

> And what does it do?

Absolutely nothing (unless `i` is defined as a macro that does something). It will be ignored.